# XSL LookUp breaking the internal references

Tags: java, xslt

I am developing an XSLT to get the internal references from the same XML file and lookups from a different Property.xml file to generate a CSV file using JAVA. The challenge here I am facing is, the internal references seem to work as expected only till the lookups is embedded in to the XSL.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repository>
<types>
    <entity-type identifier="ArticleType" identifying-field-type-ref="ArticleType.Id">
        <object-name>article</object-name>
        <class-name>ArticleType</class-name>
        <persistence-xpath>/Article</persistence-xpath>
        <persistence-class-name>db.model.Article</persistence-class-name>
        <lower-bound>1</lower-bound>
        <upper-bound>1</upper-bound>
        <field-type identifier="ArticleType.AclFlag">
            <object-name>aclFlag</object-name>
            <class-name>commons.AclFlags</class-name>
            <persistence-xpath>/aclFlag</persistence-xpath>
            <persistence-class-name>java.lang.Integer</persistence-class-name>
            <fragment-column-access>Article.AclFlag</fragment-column-access>
            <internal>true</internal>
            <lower-bound>0</lower-bound>
            <range-min></range-min>
            <range-max></range-max>
            <min-length>0</min-length>
        </field-type>
    </entity-type>
</types>
<custom>
    <category identifier="master-data" order="1">
        <name>%category.MasterData</name>
    </category>
    <enum identifier="Enum.Acls">
        <name>%enum.Acls.name</name>
        <description>%enum.Acls.description</description>
        <class-name>com.heiler.ppm.repository.enumerations.StdEnumProvider</class-name>
        <key-class-name>commons.AclFlags</key-class-name>
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.0" external-code="0" key="0" />
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.1" external-code="1" key="1" />
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.2" external-code="2" key="2" />
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.3" external-code="3" key="3" />
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.4" external-code="4" key="4" />
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.5" external-code="5" key="5" />
        <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.6" external-code="6" key="6" />
    </enum>
    <entity entity-type-ref="ArticleType" identifier="Article" parentEntities-ref="Product2G Variant">
        <name>%entity.Article.name</name>
        <description>%entity.Article.description</description>
        <label-pattern-short>{Article.SupplierAID}</label-pattern-short>
        <label-pattern-long>{Article.SupplierAID} - {ArticleLang.DescriptionShort}</label-pattern-long>
        <label-pattern-description>{ArticleLang.DescriptionLong}</label-pattern-description>
        <field identifier="Article.AclFlag" category-ref="master-data" enum-ref="Enum.Acls" field-type-ref="ArticleType.AclFlag">
            <name>%field.Article.AclFlag.name</name>
            <description>%field.Article.AclFlag.description</description>
            <editable>false</editable>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <visible-from-top>true</visible-from-top>
            <help-context></help-context>
            <mergeable>false</mergeable>
        </field>
    </entity>
</custom>
</repository>
```

**Property.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Default</comment>
<entry key="field.Article.AclFlag.name">Object right type</entry>
<entry key="category.MasterData">Header data</entry>
<entry key="enum.Acls.name">Object right types</entry>
</properties>
```

**XSL**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
 version="1.0">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:key name="kEntity" match="entity-type" use="@identifier" />
 <xsl:key name="kCategory" match="category" use="@identifier" />
 <xsl:key name="kFieldID" match="field-type" use="@identifier" />
 <xsl:key name="kEnumID" match="enum" use="@identifier" />
 <xsl:key name="k1" match="entry" use="@key"/>

 <xsl:variable name="map-doc" select="document('../transform/Properties.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"><xsl:text>FieldIdentifier|FieldName|FieldEditable| FieldVisible|FieldVisibleFromTop|FieldMaxLength|FieldExportPurpose|FieldImportPurpose|FieldUpperBound|FieldAverageLength|FieldActive|FieldMultiline|FieldDisplayByDefault|FieldRichtext|FieldValue|CategoryIdentifier|CategoryName|FieldType|FieldProxyIdentifier|FieldLowerBound|FieldRangeMin|FieldRangeMax|EnumIdentifier|EnumName|EnumLabel|EnumExternalCode|EnumKey|EntityIDentifier|EntityName|EntityParentRef</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="repository/custom/entity/field"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="field">

 <xsl:copy>
    <field>

    <xsl:value-of select="@identifier"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>


 <xsl:variable name="key-value" select="substring-after(name,'%')"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="$map-doc">
 <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $key-value)"/>
 </xsl:for-each>


    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="editable"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="visible"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="visible-from-top"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="max-length"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="exportPurpose"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="importPurpose"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="upper-bound"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="average-length"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="active"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="multiline"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="display-by-default"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="richtext"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </field>
    <category-ref-name>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kCategory', @category-ref)/@identifier"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kCategory', @category-ref)/name"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </category-ref-name>
    <field-type-ref>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/persistence-class-name, 'java.lang.')"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </field-type-ref>
    <proxy-entity-ref>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/@proxy-ref"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/lower-bound"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/range-min"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/range-max"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </proxy-entity-ref>
    <enum-ref-name>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/@identifier"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/name"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/entry">
                <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/entry">
                <xsl:value-of select="@external-code"/>
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/entry">
                <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>


    </enum-ref-name>
    <entity>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@identifier"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@parentEntities-ref"/>

    </entity>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OutPut Before the Lookup is added to XSL**
  `FieldIdentifier|FieldName|FieldEditable|FieldVisible|FieldVisibleFromTop|FieldMaxLength|FieldExportPurpose|FieldImportPurpose|FieldUpperBound|FieldAverageLength|FieldActive|FieldMultiline|FieldDisplayByDefault|FieldRichtext|FieldValue|CategoryIdentifier|CategoryName|FieldType|FieldProxyIdentifier|FieldLowerBound|FieldRangeMin|FieldRangeMax|EnumIdentifier|EnumName|EnumLabel|EnumExternalCode|EnumKey|EntityIDentifier|EntityName|EntityParentRef
Article.AclFlag|%field.Article.AclFlag.name|false|true|true|||||||||||master-data|%category.MasterData|Integer||0|||Enum.Acls|%enum.Acls.name|%enum.Acls.entry.0;%enum.Acls.entry.1;%enum.Acls.entry.2;%enum.Acls.entry.3;%enum.Acls.entry.4;%enum.Acls.entry.5;%enum.Acls.entry.6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|Article|%entity.Article.name|Product2G Variant`

**Output After the Lookup is added to XSL**
    `FieldIdentifier|FieldName|FieldEditable|FieldVisible|FieldVisibleFromTop|FieldMaxLength|FieldExportPurpose|FieldImportPurpose|FieldUpperBound|FieldAverageLength|FieldActive|FieldMultiline|FieldDisplayByDefault|FieldRichtext|FieldValue|CategoryIdentifier|CategoryName|FieldType|FieldProxyIdentifier|FieldLowerBound|FieldRangeMin|FieldRangeMax|EnumIdentifier|EnumName|EnumLabel|EnumExternalCode|EnumKey|EntityIDentifier|EntityName|EntityParentRef
Article.AclFlag|Object right type|false|true|true|||||||||||||||||||||||Article|%entity.Article.name|Product2G Variant`

**Expected Output**
`FieldIdentifier|FieldName|FieldEditable|FieldVisible|FieldVisibleFromTop|FieldMaxLength|FieldExportPurpose|FieldImportPurpose|FieldUpperBound|FieldAverageLength|FieldActive|FieldMultiline|FieldDisplayByDefault|FieldRichtext|FieldValue|CategoryIdentifier|CategoryName|FieldType|FieldProxyIdentifier|FieldLowerBound|FieldRangeMin|FieldRangeMax|EnumIdentifier|EnumName|EnumLabel|EnumExternalCode|EnumKey|EntityIDentifier|EntityName|EntityParentRef
Article.AclFlag|Object right type|false|true|true|||||||||||master-data|Header data|Integer||0|||Enum.Acls|Object right types|%enum.Acls.entry.0;%enum.Acls.entry.1;%enum.Acls.entry.2;%enum.Acls.entry.3;%enum.Acls.entry.4;%enum.Acls.entry.5;%enum.Acls.entry.6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|Article|%entity.Article.name|Product2G Variant`

Comment: i have doubt on <xsl:for-each select="$map-doc"> you are running loop on file?

Comment: @AmrendraKumar, no, I am not doing any loop intentionally. Can you advice me, if it is doing so. The idea is to get only the name using the key from the properties xml file and retain the other internal references as it is .

Comment: @AmrendraKumar did you get a chance to look in to this? I did check again, if I am looping on a file and is not the case here. Thanks